# Salary Range Negotiation

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

Suppose a company advertises a salary range between $80K-$200K. If a person is given a job offer with a salary of $100K, is it usually very difficult for him to negotiate an offer of say $190K compared to say $120K?

Comment: That is an unlikely salary band.  Maybe 80 to 120, or 150 to 200.

Comment: What is the question? Currently it sounds like [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Just to add to this - I would be *Extremely* wary of such a wide Salary Band in any Job advert. Normally when such a wide *earnings* band is indicated, it's due to the job being either primarily commission based or a role where 'celebrity' is involved (e.g. your salary is dependent on your individual brand recognition). These sorts of roles are fine for those that do that sort of work - but if it doesn't fall within those scopes - I'd be wary of an attempted bait-and-switch.

Comment: @TheDemonLord that's one possibility, but in that case they probably wouldn't be offering $100k up front it's be $50k and teasing with the prospect of those huge commissions.  I think it's more likely that they're just open to hiring someone at a wide range of experience levels (plausible if they're either hiring a lot of people, or are a contractor doing lots of short term projects - in which case they don't have a highly defined role they're looking to fill long term).  Another possibility would be malicious compliance with non-discrimination laws requiring a salary range to be posted.

Comment: This question:  Is it harder to negotiate a 90% increase than a 20% increase.  Seriously?

Comment: It's not super unlikely to have these extremely wide bands anymore; with places like NYC now legally requiring companies to post their salaries on the job adverts, companies have tried to get around the law by posting such a wide range as to be useless. In light of these new developments, I think the previous question 'Requesting Salary Outside of Advertised Range' no longer quite applies, as this poster is asking for salary within the range, even if the range is essentially a farce.

Answer (score 3):

> is it usually very difficult for him to negotiate an offer of say
> $190K compared to say $120K?

Yes.

A 58% difference from what you were offered is often very difficult to negotiate, certainly harder than a 20% difference.

You can always try. It depends on how good you are, and how badly they want you.

Lying about your current salary is a mistake. You would be better off saying that you require $x without revealing your current salary.

Comment: @@JoeStrazzere: The point is would I be able to get a salary closer to $200K if I tell them that I make $150K at my current position?

Comment: If you make $150K now, why would you take 120k? You should certainly counter for higher.  But Joe's answer stands -- it depends on how much they want you.

Comment: @NebulousReveal probably not.  They're going to have a reasonable idea what people at various experience levels are worth paying.  Advertising a $80-200k range means they're open to hiring someone from a relatively junior to very senior role (or somewhat lower on the scale in SF, NYC, etc); not that they're open to paying a relatively junior person like a team lead.  Even getting $120k, unless you're able to convince them that they mis-evaluated your skill and experience level. is very optimistic.

Answer (score 2):

A salary range that great will usually mean that what the candidate is ultimately offered will be based on their experience and knowledge.  Unless you can convince the company that the experience and knowledge that you presented in your resume and interview(s) is significantly greater, you will have a very hard time negotiating such a large increase.  Some companies, being presented with such an insulting counter-offer, would simply retract the original offer and remove you from consideration for being unreasonable.

Comment: Trying to nearly double their offer has a low likelihood of success.  Most companies have some room to work with you, but 90% is a big difference

Comment: @cdkMoose: Even if I tell them that I make say $150K at my current position?

Comment: @sf02: Even if I tell I tell them that I make $150K at my current position?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: The point is would I be able to get a salary closer to $200K if I tell them that I make $150K?

Comment: @NebulousReveal, if we're going to lie about our current salary why not say 180K , much closer to 200K

Comment: @user21478 It's never a good idea to start off any employment with dishonesty.

Comment: @cdkMoose: I am not lying that is how much I make.@sf02: I am lying that is how much I make

Comment: If they're offering 100 and your minimum acceptable is 150, you can certainly ask. They are unlikely to say yes. They may decide to move on to the next candidate since you don't seem to be interested. Up to you to decide whether and how you want to try this, based on your own understanding of your skills, the market, and the company.